# ASP.NET MVC5 LDAP Authentication fails over to use AD ports

Tags: authentication, ldap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an ASP.NET MVC5 Application which I am trying to authenticate against an LDAP server on port 636.  I can see the bind account authenticate on port 636 but when the application goes to authenticate the user I get an error:

> The specified domain or server could not be contacted

However with wireshark I can see the traffic going over on the correct port when my connection username is authenticating.  The error happens when I try to authenticate my login user.  For some reason it is trying to communicate on 445 when it goes to authenticate my login user.

Here is my connection string and membership provder in web.config.

```
<add name="ADCon" connectionString="LDAP://ldap.xxx.xxx.edu:636/DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=edu"/>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear />
              <add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
                   type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
                   connectionStringName="ADCon"
                   connectionProtection="Secure"
                   connectionUsername="ldap-auth"
                   connectionPassword="pwd"
                   attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
          </providers>
    </membership>
```

If I open port 445 and 139 it works without an issue.  But of course on our production environment we can only use ldap over 636.  Why does this authenticate the connectionUsername account fine over 636 but then switch over to 445 when logging in the application user?  Any way to get an MVC 5 app to authenticate only using ldap ports?

Comment: I am facing the same challenge. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @BjørnFridal No I did not.  I am only using the application internally at the moment so it is not a huge issue.  If we go externally then it will be.  I don't know why it insists on switching over to AD ports for user auth.  Once I get back to this application and find a solution I will update.